# Cannot open an url (empty buffer)

Tags: invocation, netrw

I have some strange troubles with opening an url in vim. Judging from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3153102/1423473), this should be pretty easy, but when I'm doing this:

```
$ vim http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7386.txt
```

I getting a message

```
:!links 'http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7386.txt' -source > '/tmp/vmEga7/1.txt'
```

and empty buffer (there is no `/tmp/vmEga7/1.txt` file also). I don't fully understand, where I should look for the options that are related to the `links` (some vim options, xdg configuration, etc.) - probably someone know about this and can explain it to me?

**UPD** I'm trying to debug this problem

```
$ vim -V20vimlog http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7386.txt
```

and [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/erthalion/7f53f268d2d2c5b90ce3/raw/66688a36cc353d98099d7d3c82e140bef3e85d88/vimlog) is the part of vimlog. Is this line

```
function netrw#Nread..netrw#NetRead..<SNR>24_FileReadable returning #1
```

means, that resulting temporary file isn't readable?

**UPD** I'm still struggling with this trouble, no luck. It's strange, but the same is perfectly working in NeoVim. I figured out, that everything is ok about temporary files (they are created well and are readable). It looks like temporary file should be opened here:

```
   " edit temporary file (ie. read the temporary file in)
   if     rfile =~ '\.zip$'
"    call Decho("handling remote zip file with zip#Browse(tfile<".tfile.">)")
    call zip#Browse(tfile)
   elseif rfile =~ '\.tar$'
"    call Decho("handling remote tar file with tar#Browse(tfile<".tfile.">)")
    call tar#Browse(tfile)
   elseif rfile =~ '\.tar\.gz$'
"    call Decho("handling remote gzip-compressed tar file")
    call tar#Browse(tfile)
   elseif rfile =~ '\.tar\.bz2$'
"    call Decho("handling remote bz2-compressed tar file")
    call tar#Browse(tfile)
   elseif rfile =~ '\.tar\.xz$'
"    call Decho("handling remote xz-compressed tar file")
    call tar#Browse(tfile)
   elseif rfile =~ '\.txz$'
"    call Decho("handling remote xz-compressed tar file (.txz)")
    call tar#Browse(tfile)
   else
"    call Decho("edit temporary file")
    NetrwKeepj e!
   endif
```

but when control flow reaches line `NetrwKeepj e!` nothing is happening.

Comment: See if  :help netrw-debug  will help you with its addtional information on your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I get a different result when I go this: the buffer consists of garbled text (gziped?). Perhaps your version of `links` and/or `vim` does something different with gzip-encoded text.

Netrw, the plugin bundled with Vim which reads URLs tries a bunch of different commands to get the source of a page, but you can also set it explicitly.

For example, to set it to `curl`:

```
" Command name
let g:netrw_http_cmd = 'curl'

" Arguments passed to the command
let g:netrw_http_xcmd = '-o'
```

Or you can try `wget`:

```
let g:netrw_http_cmd = 'wget'
let g:netrw_http_xcmd = '-q -O'
```

Also see `:help g:netrw_http_cmd` and `:help g:netrw_http_xcmd`.

Comment: I've tried to setup `curl` example, now I got this message: `:!curl 'http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7386.txt' -o '/tmp/vbA49BG/1.txt'`, but anyway there is nothing in directory `/tmp/vbA49BG/`. Whem I'm executing this command right from the terminal `curl 'http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7386.txt' -o '/tmp/vbA49BG/1.txt`, everything is ok. It looks like something wrong with file creation.

Comment: @erthalion This is also the case on my system. The `/tmp/[...]` directory is empty. This is I would expect, since tmp files are exactly that: temporarily... For some reason, the directory is removed later (perhaps there is a reason for this, but it could also be a bug).

Comment: Not a bug.  The directory is reused for other temporary files, and it's removed when you quit Vim.

Comment: @lcd047 temporary directory is empty even before I quit vim, is that ok?

Comment: @erthalion Yes.  On UNIX it's ok to delete files from disk while they are still open (the process holding them open won't notice).  Doing this is a common practice with temporary files.